# How can I call this function in viewDidLoad() in iOS8

Tags: swift, ios8, swifty-json

I want to call this function in `viewDidLoad` but I don't know how one would do this. Can you please help me?

```
  func loginWithFacebook(withcompletionHandler: (success:Bool) ->()){
        var permissions : Array = [ "user_location","public_profile"]
        PFFacebookUtils.logInInBackgroundWithReadPermissions(permissions, {
            (user: PFUser?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if let user = user {
                if user.isNew {
                    println("User SIGNED UP and logged in through Facebook!")
                    self.fetchUserInforFromFacebook(withcompletionHandler)

                    println("User logged in through Facebook!")
                    withcompletionHandler(success: true)
                }
            } else {
                println("Uh oh. The user cancelled the FACEBOOK LOGIN.")
                self.showErrorMessage(error!)
                withcompletionHandler(success: false)
            }
        })
    }
```

Comment: Maybe something like:         loginWithFacebook { (success) -> () in
            if success
            {
                //succeeded
            }
            else
            {
                //failed
            }
        }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()
   self.loginWithFacebook { (success) -> () in
     if success { //succeeded } else { //failed } }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you  call function with in function

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.loginWithFacebook { (success) -> () in
        // Your code.
    }
}
```

if you want call it in same function then

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    loginWithFacebook { (success) -> () in
        // Your code.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So in order to call your method, add this to your `viewDidLoad`:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.loginWithFacebook { (success) -> () in
        // Your code.
    }
}
```